# Main server 2008R2 crashed. Need to copy AD from another server in same IP range

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, migration, replication

Unfortunately the main server crashed and I have re-installed Server 2008 R2 Standard in it. The server had only ADDS, DNS Services and File Services. I have the AD on a desktop computer where Server 2008 R2 Standard is installed. All the user computers and the servers are in same IP range. I tried replication but an error pops up saying "you will not be able to install a writable replica domain controller at this time because the RID master DC-TURBO.turbo.com is offline"

How do I resolve this issue and bring my new domain controller up?

Comment: Well, reassign the RID master. Not so hard - google can tell you how. I vote to close here.

Answer (score 5):

You'll have to reassign or seize the RID master role on a functioning domain controller.  Microsoft says:

> Do not seize the RID master role if you can transfer it instead.
>   Seizing the RID master is a drastic step that should be considered
>   only if the current operations master will never be available again.
>   For more information about transferring operations master roles, see
>   Related Topics.

So it sounds like you'll have to seize, but I'm going to include reassigning anyway because of the above text.  (I've copied and pasted in case of link rot.)

To [reassign](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781063%28v=ws.10%29.aspx):

1. Open Active Directory Users and Computers.
2. In the console tree, right-click Active Directory Users and Computers, and then click Connect to Domain Controller.
3. In Enter the name of another domain controller, type the name of the domain controller you want to hold the RID master role.
4. Or, click the domain controller in the list of available domain controllers.
5. In the console tree, right-click Active Directory Users and Computers, point to All Tasks, and then click Operations Masters.
6. Click the RID tab, and then click Change.

To [seize](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc784077%28v=ws.10%29.aspx):

1. Open Command Prompt.
2. Type:  `ntdsutil`
3. At the ntdsutil command prompt, type:  `roles`
4. At the fsmo maintenance command prompt, type: `connections`
5. At the server connections command prompt, type:  `connect to serverDomainController`
6. At the server connections prompt, type: `quit`
7. At the fsmo maintenance command prompt, type: `seize RID master`

Aside:  You probably already realize this, so I apologize for rubbing it in, but it sounds like you need better backups.  Please consider implementing something as soon as you resolve the current crisis.  [Windows Server Backup](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772523.aspx) is free with your version of Windows.